# Transformation matrix 3d beam element

Tags: matrices, transformation

I am currently doing my bsc thesis and I need to find the systems stiffness matrix of a beam structure in 3d. I have the element matrix of all the beams but I need to rotate them to the global system. They are only rotated along the z-axis and I know the angles. Everywhere I see people talking about the rotation matrix where Kg = T' * Kel * T. But I can't find a proper description of this T matrix. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Have you tried consulting a textbook ?